# Input data with Excel VBA in javascript webpage

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I'm trying to interatc with a HTML webpage with excel VBA.
This is my code:

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim IEDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim IE_test As New InternetExplorer

    IE_test.navigate "https://cvatrading.cvaspa.it/irj/portal/anonymous/login"
    IE_test.Visible = True
    'IE_test.Width = 500
    'IE_test.Height = 500

        Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)

        IE_test.document.getElementById("logonuidfield").Value = "userXXX"
        IE_test.document.getElementById("logonpassfield").Value = "passwordXXX"

        Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

        With IE_test.document
            Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("input")
            For Each e In elems
                If (e.getAttribute("value") = "Eseguire logon") Then
                    e.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next e
        End With

        Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)

        With IE_test.document
            Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each e In elems
                If e.innerText = "Report" Then
                    e.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next e
        End With

        Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)

        With IE_test.document
            Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each e In elems
                If e.innerText = "Curve di Carico" Then
                    e.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next e
        End With

        Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)

        ' Javascript?
        IE_test.document.getElementById("aaaa.ReadCurveDiCaricoView.InputFieldPOD").Value = "XXX"
```

The code works until the last line

```
IE_test.document.getElementById("aaaa.ReadCurveDiCaricoView.InputFieldPOD").Value = "XXX"
```

I think because this is javascript form or similar, in fact if I save that webpage I don't find that line... (sorry but this is my first time with VBA-HTML).

https://imageshack.com/a/img923/2826/LvH6RO.jpg

How can i put some data in that form?
Thank you very much.

Comment: The error is: "Runtime Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: Yes sorry, this is the html webpage: https://justpaste.it/4eghv

Comment: Yes I know (I think because this is javascript form or similar, in fact if I save that webpage I don't find that line), now I try to put the code of " Firefox inspect element"...

Comment: https://justpaste.it/5ex40 this is part of inspect element...

Comment: There  has to be something else going on with your set-up I think as the querySelector I tried works on selecting from the html provided.

Comment: Are you still getting an error with  While IE_test.document.Busy Or IE_test.document.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend?